# SQL where clause effect on table output w.r.t bytes?

Tags: sql, syntax

I have sql query as

```
select sourceIP, sum(sourceBytes) 
from flows group by sourceIP
order by sum(sourceBytes) desc
```

This brings result (dummy) as:-

```
sourceIp     SourceBytes
192.168.1.2  100
192.168.1.3  79
192.168.1.4  67
192.168.1.5  4
192.168.1.6  4
```

Now if I change the query to

```
select sourceIP, sum(sourceBytes) 
from flows group where sourceBytes > 50 by sourceIP
order by sum(sourceBytes) desc
```

The output be

```
 sourceIp        SourceBytes
 192.168.1.2     150
 192.168.1.3     40
```

I don't have access to DB right now, I cannot pull /show real table values, but the point here I want to make with the `greater` then statement the output is changed. I was of the view with second query I just want to process the results instead of all the values present `flows` table to just values which are greater range i.e 50. I want to know what level these two queries are not the same. Thanks.

Comment: What DB is this?  MySQL, SqlServer, Oracle?

Comment: @Siyual what you don't understand?

Comment: Assuming I'm right in thinking you want the HAVING clause, your sample data is all wrong ... your problem is that you were expecting the values that stayed in the result set to be the same, but they changed because you were filtering at the detail level with a WHERE clause, rather than at the aggregate level with the HAVING statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I *think* that you are looking for [the HAVING clause](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v10/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.sqlt.doc/sqltmst101.htm) ... i.e., you want to filter already-grouped totals to only see the ones that have a cumulative SourceBytes total over 50.  You're using the WHERE clause to do it, with the result that the only values being considered are those where the SourceBytes value on the individual row is over 50.

That's because the WHERE clause is applied at the row level of your source table, whereas the HAVING clause is applied to the results that came out of your GROUP BY / aggregate statements.

In that case, you are probably looking for (can't remember if the IBM syntax is different than SQL):

```
select sourceIP, sum(sourceBytes) TotalBytes
from flows 
group by sourceIP
having sum(SourceBytes) > 50
order by sum(sourceBytes) desc
```